# How execute first jquery before my php classes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Hi how can I execute first my jQuery scripts before my php code.
Here is my (javascript/jQuert) code:

```
function success_callback(p)
{
    jQuery.post("http://geolocation.php", { latlong: LatLong, country: CountryName, city: LocaLityName},

    function(data){
       jQuery("#debug").text(data); 
       jQuery("div").show();    
       });

}
```

PHP CLASS located in geolocation.php:

```
$data = array();
$data['id'] = 267722;
$data['latlong'] = $_POST['latlong'];
$data['country'] = $_POST['country'];
$data['city'] = $_POST['city']; 

print_r($data);

GetLatLong::GetLocation($_SESSION['cId'],$_POST['latlong'], $_POST['country'], $_POST['city']);

    if($flag == true){
    new Statistics($data, $db, $type);
}
```

The `new Statistics($data, $db, $type);` code is always execute even I put a flag on it.

Comment: Client side Javascript can *never* execute before server side PHP in the same page load cycle. What are you trying to do? It's not entirely clear from your code dump.

Comment: i need to post a data using jQuery.post() to geolocation.php but before posting i need to revariable my post data to $data = $_POST[latlong] before the new statistics($data,$db) executes;

Comment: So, where do you set that $flag? And, try using === instead of == . Anyway, I don't understand the question. Rather cancel it and describe what you want to achieve, in high-level terms.

Comment: @ondra the flag is inside the GetLatLong class.

Comment: this is the output when i load the page and print_r($data).Array ( [id] => 26 [latlong] => [country] => [city] => ) but at the bottom of my firebug i read my posted data latlong,country,city has a post values.

Comment: I've done already putting my flags on __construct($flag == false){}

Comment: @khem, I agree with @Ondra Žižka - please try to say what you want to achieve.  I think that what you say you want to do is nearly impossible or at least based on some misunderstanding you have.

Comment: thank you all for the answers thank you guys...^_^

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP is being called by the jQuery, then by definition, isn't the jQuery running first?

As to the new Statistics always being executed even when you put a flag on it, perhaps its because you never actually initialized the flag?